# AngularJS UI-Router: Rendering parent partial with child partial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I'm using the [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)  framework for AngularJS in order to render nested partials. I'm having problems with rendering a parent partial with its child partial. Here is my code:

```
window.app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('class', {
        url: '/classes/:classId',
        templateUrl: '/views/class.html',
        controller: 'ClassCtrl',
    })
      .state('class.questionList', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: '/views/questionList.html',
      })
  }]);
```

In the declaration of my child-state, I set the url to an empty string so that it would render at the same time as its parent. However, this is not working, only the parent view is rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the property "abstract: true" to the parent state, to inform UI-Router that this state can only be activated through the activation of a child state. This will make the URL /classes/:classId activate both states.

Comment: oh easy! thanks much, I must have overlooked that in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Having child state implicitly means that you want to navigate to that state from an existing state and this should update the url that matches the state.

From your route it looks like you want do show something in a `ui-view` of `class.html`, but do not want the state to change to child. Better to use `ng-include` which would serve the purpose nicely

In you `class.html`, where you have added `ui-view` use ng-include

```
<ng-include src="'/views/questionList.html'"></ng-include>
```

Comment: I considered using ng-include, however in the very near future I'd like to be able to dynamically swap out the child view with another view. From what I've learned, I wouldn't be able to do this with ng-include right?

Comment: You are right, but how this state view work is that they too look at url to decide when the state changed. Look at ui-view documentation, abstract view are also there, those may help you. Basically there should be a way to differentiate when you are on a parent view only and when you are on parent->child view. In your case the router cannot differentiate.

Comment: ok gotcha. so I think another solution would be to just pass a url to the class.questionList state and redirect the original url to that one?

Comment: Yes there should be something in the url property for child state.